# How to correctly bridge my KVM's in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, kvm, bridge

i have a HOST linux 16.04 ubuntu machine & inside this i have a couple of containers.

I have some applications running on these containers , the IP address of these containers are as follows:

```
 192.168.122.226
 192.168.122.254
 192.168.122.199
 192.168.122.146
 192.168.122.242
 192.168.122.59
 192.168.122.195
 192.168.122.224
 192.168.122.125
 192.168.122.67
```

Now these are the default private ip that i got while i created these containers. The IP of my HOST is 10.164.27.149 (Private) {THIS IS FROM DHCP} , Now i wanted to access the above KVM VM's from outside i mean i should directly be able to SSH or Ping into the above KVM VM's but i can't reach them without logging into the HOST and then from HOST to VM.

I bridged the host also as follows:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eno1
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

Can someone please guide me here on how to properly network these?

Answer (score -2):

You need configure iptables on your host.
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking

This is your situation.
https://serverfault.com/questions/442143/kvm-guest-with-nat-bridged-networking

Comment: Do you want to elaborate?